# dplyr & dataset: how to sum values referred to same individuals and merge them in another dataset?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, sum, dataset

I'm doing a mess in merging datasets.

I have two dataset: "data" and "allb".

The common variables in them are `nquest` and `nord`

- nquest = is the code for the family
- nord = is the number of the individual in the family ( for example 1 for the first, 2 for the second, ect)

Here a sample of the "data"

```
nquest nord sex anasc ireg eta staciv studio asnonoc nace nesplav exlav etalav 
173    1   1  1948   18  64      3      5      4   19       1    NA     23      
375    1   2  1925   16  87      4      2      1    7       1    NA     35      
629    1   1  1939    5  73      4      3      1    3       1    NA     15      
632    1   1  1950    5  62      1      3      2   15       1    NA     22      
633    1   2  1934    5  78      4      2      1    1       4     1     18      
1238   1   1  1937   15  75      4      3      1    3       1    NA     40      
1367   1   1  1927   18  85      1      2      1    1       1    NA     17      
7886   1   1  1950    9  62      1      5      2   11       1    NA     23      
11972  2   1  1938   17  74      1      2      9    7       2     3     24      
20174  1   1  1941    8  71      1      5      2   11       1    NA     21      
20174  2   2  1942    8  70      1      3      1    7       1    NA     15      
20223  1   2  1938    3  74      1      5      2    3       1    NA     18      
20223  2   1  1939    3  73      1      4      8    3       2     3     13      
20711  2   1  1944    4  68      1      2      1    6       3     1     14      
20837  1   1  1931    8  81      1      4      2   11       3     1     18      
20837  2   2  1928    8  84      1      2      1    7       1    NA     16      
21461  1   2  1918    5  94      4      2      1    1       4     1     11      
22173  1   1  1938   15  74      1      2      1    9       1    NA     15      
22208  1   2  1935    5  77      4      2      1    3       1    NA     15      
22222  1   1  1927    5  85      4      2      2    3       1    NA     14
```

and this is a sample of "allb"

```
nquest nord tpens
173    1  2500
375    1   409
629    1  1188
629    1    NA
629    1   181
632    1  1320
633    1   350
633    1   800
923    1   470
1238   1  1000
1367   1   500
1367   2   500
1927   1   790
1946   1   890
2274   1   400
2274   1   320
2485   1   600
2886   1  1211
7165   1  1100
7165   1   450
```

The first thing that I need is to sum all the values of the variable `tpens` (of the dataset "allb") that are referred to the same individual in the family. `nquest` is the code of the family and `nord` is the number of the individual inside ( it is not an identification code unfortunately, but only is position in the family). To identify the same individual it is necessary to set the sum such that `nquest` and `nord` are the same. If `nquest` is the same but  `nord` is different, it means that the values is for another member of the same family.

I've tried to do that (setting equal 0 the NA values)

```
allb %>%
      replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
      group_by(nquest, nord) %>% 
      sum(tpens)

Error in allb %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% group_by(nquest, nord) %>%  : 
  object 'tpens' not found
```

Then I've tried with `summarise`

```
allb %>%
     replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
     group_by(nquest, nord) %>% 
     summarize(sum(tpens))

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'nquest'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

I'm not sure it is the right way because it gives me problem when I try to merge the dataset after and because "allb" ends up with 5992 obs, while "data" has 4396 ( they should be on the same individuals if my sample selection is right)

To go ahead i've now tried to merge the 2 dataset

```
allb <- rename(allb, `tpens` = `sum(tpens)`)

final <- dplyr::inner_join(data, allb, by = c("nquest","nord"))
```

which works, but probably there is something wrong in this because if I try a simple linear regression with this final dataset I get

```
lm(log(tpens) ~ sex + eta + ireg + studio, data = final)

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm setting something wrong in the beginning or during the merge... Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

I've followed the instruction of @Akrun and it works. Now the code is

```
allb2 <- allb %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  group_by(nquest, nord) %>% 
  summarize(tpens = sum(tpens), .groups = 'drop')
```

There is still something that I don't understand. If I run the summary of the original `allb`, I get

```
> summary(allb$tpens)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
    103     670    1000    1088    1350    8000      27
```

Now, after the sum I get

```
> summary(allb2$tpens)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0     700    1000    1106    1400    8000
```

How is that possible that the minimum value is 0 now (which is the reason why the regression doesn't work), if before was 103?

I've uploded the dataset

https://easyupload.io/bxfic6

Comment: hi @akrun and thanks for the answer! I've done it also with summarise, as you can read in my post, but it gives me problem anyway... Do you know any other way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at your first error.  The second is just a warning, you can ignore it or use `.groups = "drop"`

Comment: yes @akrun, i've done in that way, but why the regression doesn't work?

Comment: @akrun how is that possible if i've set `allb %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%` ???

Comment: hi @akrun , I don't know what github is but I've saved the dataset that I'm using and uploded it here. I hope it is the same thing.... Why do I get zero values when I make the sum if the lowest one is 103 ? Hope you are not angry with me

Comment: The issue with downloading from that link is concerning the safety.  Sorry, I can't test it from that site

Comment: @akrun I come back here to choose your answer as "the one" but I didn't find also it anymore :( . have you any idea why I get zeros when I do the sum?

Comment: It is because you are replacing NA to 0 and if there are some groups having only 0s (after the replacement), then the sum will also be 0 right.  If 0s are an issue, you could also filter out those groups i.e. `allb2 <- allb %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  group_by(nquest, nord) %>% 
  summarize(tpens = sum(tpens), .groups = 'keep') %>% filter(!all(tpens == 0))%>% ungroup`

Comment: @akrun I try to understand how this github works and find a way to share the dataset throught it.... Just give me some minutes, I'm pretty new in this kind of stuff

Comment: @akrun you are right! I'm feeling pretty dumb... Maybe is better that I remove all the NA values

Comment: Can you try `allb2 <- allb %>%   replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%   group_by(nquest, nord) %>%    summarize(tpens = sum(tpens), .groups = 'keep') %>% filter(!all(tpens == 0))%>% ungroup` and use `allb2`

Comment: Sorry, i have to leave now.  Hope this fix works for you